# Index Match with three variables in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

In the workbook on the left I have a list of Years (column A) and Country Codes (column B), and then on the top row a long list of World Bank development indicator names (columns C, D, E, etc.). In the workbook on on the right I have the values for each indicator for each year and each country. What I would like to do is to use a formula (index match or something else) in order to get the values for the indicators for the corresponding years and countries. Could anyone provide me with the formula that would solve this problem so I can apply it to all rows and columns? Thank you in advance for your help!:)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? The community will be willing to help if you could elaborate further on the things you've experimented with so far.

Comment: break your sample data down to something slightly smaller that gives the same effect.  In your images the names across the top are cut off, and the name in the second and third column are cut off as well.  This makes it hard to see how things relate.  ie does the third column even come into play.

Answer (score 0):

its an ARRAY Formula. You need to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

`{=INDEX($C$4:$E$15,MATCH(1,(A4:A15=$A$25)*(B4:B15=B25),0),MATCH(C24,C3:E3,0))}`

[image: Array]