# Multidimensional lookup (2 rows and 1 column) with row labels out-of-line

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create a function that will fill in cells `Sheet2!G25:P25` according to three criteria: project type, criteria type, and date.  The problem is that the criteria in `Sheet 1` aren't lined up to conveniently use a `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` `MATCH`.  I know I'm supposed to list the formula that doesn't work but I honestly haven't even been able to get close.  I've been primarily working on variations of the `SUMPRODUCT` such as

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A3:A19=Sheet2!A25)*(Sheet1!D3:D19=Sheet2!B25)*(Sheet1!G2:P2=Sheet2!G23)*Sheet1!G3:P19)
```

but that obviously won't work since the project type and criteria type aren't on the same row as the data I need.  A work around I've been trying is to `OFFSET` the location of the cell found in the `SUMPRODUCT` project type and criteria type arrays but restrictions within the `OFFSET` function has set me back.  For example, the reference section of the `OFFSET` function cannot be a function even if the function pulls a cell location `(OFFSET(CELL("address",INDEX MATCH),0,0)`.  The goal of this was to trick the `SUMPRODUCT` function into thinking that the 2 row criteria were on the same row. You guys are geniuses when it comes to this stuff so I'm sure I'm missing something.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A3:A19=Sheet2!A25)*(Sheet1!D3:D19=Sheet2!B25)*(Sheet1!G2:P2=Sheet2!G23)*Sheet1!G3:P19)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296036/index-match-with-three-variables-in-excel) suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the following works for me on the basis or your example.
The condition here is that the row separation between your project and the criteria is always 4 rows apart

The formula on Sheet 2 is

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$U$19,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$15=$A$3)*(Sheet1!$D$4:$D$18=$B$3),0)+1,MATCH(H1,Sheet1!$A$1:$U$1,0))}
```

This is an array formula, enter it by usind Ctrl+Shift+Enter

On sheet1 if positioned the data same as on your picture, that means the first date is in H1 on Sheet 1
The first formula entered on Sheet 2 is in cell H3

The "trick" I used is to simply offset the second search array:

- Project uses A$1:$A$15
- Criteria uses $D$4:$D$18